# React Table data displaying incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, html-table, datatables, react-table

I am getting the data in the following manner. Although I want the row and column data to be interchanged i.e I want Customer Age, CRM and 41562434 under Age column and so on. Below is my table code:

```html
    {!isLoading ? (
     
<table class="table table-bordered table-secondary" id="tableBorder">
     
       <thead class="first">{
     users.map(user => {
   const { featureName} = user; 
   return (
<th style={{ color: "black" }}>{featureName}</th> 
        );
      })     
     } </thead>
     <>
     {
      users.map(user => {
    const { featureTechDescription, sourceSystem, sampleValues} = user; 
    return (
<>
 <tr><td>{featureTechDescription}</td>
  <td>{sourceSystem}</td> 
 <td>{sampleValues}</td></tr>  
</>
         );        
       })   }</>    
      </table>
      ) : (<h3>Loading...</h3>)    
   }
```

[image]

Sample data of the json response that I am trying to consume:---

```
[
    {
        "featureName": "Age",
        "featureTechDescription": "Customer Age in Whole Months",
        "sourceSystem": "CRM",
        "sampleValues": [
            "41",
            "56",
            "24",
            "34"
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureName": "Martial Status",
        "featureTechDescription": "Marital status of borrower",
        "sourceSystem": "CRM",
        "sampleValues": [
            "Married",
            "Single",
            "Divorced",
            "Not Disclosed"
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureName": "Customer Since",
        "featureTechDescription": "Date of start of relationship between bank and borrower",
        "sourceSystem": "CRM",
        "sampleValues": [
            "1/10/2015"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you show us the rest of the code of the table?

Comment: Updated the entire table code... Here, the featureName needs to be the header, which is Age, Maritial status and customer since..

Comment: please also include sample data that you are mapping.

Comment: Updated sample data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display each user on his own column. Here is a small working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dawn-qn6io

Don't forget to use `key` for each user, if you do a map in react.

```
      <table className="table table-bordered table-secondary" id="tableBorder">
        <thead className="first">
          <tr>
            {users.map(user => (
              <th key={user.featureName} style={{ color: "black" }}>
                {user.featureName}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {["featureTechDescription", "sourceSystem", "sampleValues"].map(
            key => (
              <tr key={key}>
                {users.map(user => (
                  <td key={user.featureName}>{user[key]}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            )
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: So the key feature I wasn't using.. Thankyou so much, it is working exactly as I expected!! :)